# SharePoint Search refiner does not work after loading Angular library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, enterprise-search, angularjs

SharePoint search refiner adds **slash(/)** between **#k and #s** parameters then refinement panel does not work property with ***out of the box*** behavior.

After work around found that this happens after **AngularJS** libraries are loaded.

Answer (score 2):

This happens  because of Angular forces HashBang mode by default and it listens for URL changes then override the hash(#) queries which append by SharePoint refiner. You can avoid this by enabling HTML5Mode but its not a permanent solution.[More details on angular location provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('*');
```

**Permanent solution would be** ***disabling all location*** manipulations in angular app which can be achieved by following code snippet.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.config( ['$provide', function ($provide){
    $provide.decorator('$browser', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
        $delegate.onUrlChange = function () {};
        $delegate.url = function () { return ""};
        return $delegate;
    }]);
}]);
```

*Note: Just use this in your app config of angular (i.e. app.js or in angular config location)*